# How to convert Flex 3.6 Project into Flex 4.6 Project (SDK)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

How to convert my Flex 3.6 Project SDK into Flex 4.6 SDK ?

I'm doing following way

```
right click on Project-->Properties-->Flex Compiler-->click on Use Specific SDK radioButton and select 3.6 to 4.6.
```

when do like this i got lot of compile errors?

Give me suggestion..

Comment: The major versions are not fully backwards compatible, so you'll have to step through all those errors and fix them.

Comment: Unless you tell us what the errors are then we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct convertion between both SDK's, as Flex4.6 has a lot of differences and is not fully backwards compatible.

The easiness of that task depends on what your Flex3.6 project uses. In example, if you use Flex states in 3.6, you have a lot of changes to port your code to 4.6, because there's big differences in that.